# Chef Server. Upgrade embedded PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

I need to upgrade PostgreSQL that comes with Chef Server.

```
/opt/opscode/embedded/postgresql/9.2
```

It's been installed from binaries, not apt, and the installation directory path suggests that it's an `embedded` version. Although I'm able to access it remotely just fine.

Has anyone tried patching the built-in PostgreSQL that comes with Chef?

My target version is 9.5 as I need support of json functions available in 9.5.

Comment: 9.5 is still in Beta. I guess most packagers won't have touched it yet. If you have a (cross)compiler, compilation from source is an option.

Comment: I can go to 9.4 as well as I mostly need to_json function to decode ahoi attributes stored in nodes tables. 9.4 has it http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html. I just installed the chef on ubuntu 14 LTS, that's it.

Comment: It should work fine, but you have to upgrade the database. Either dump, initdb and reload, or use `pg_upgrade`. See the PostgreSQL manual for details on upgrading. Either way, keep a backup.